# Custom discrete color scale in plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I would like to customize the colors in a `plotly` plot. This works fine for continuous variables and scales as per the [docs](https://plot.ly/r/user-guide/#sequential-color-mappings):

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(iris, x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width,
             color = Sepal.Length, colors = c("#132B43", "#56B1F7"),
             mode = "markers")
```

If I make the argument to color discrete (character or factor), however, this still works but throws a warning:

```
> plot_ly(iris, x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width,
          color = Sepal.Length>6, colors = c("#132B43", "#56B1F7"),
          mode = "markers")


Warning message:
In RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(N, "Set2") :
  minimal value for n is 3, returning requested palette with 3 different levels
```

How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't a plotly issue, but a design feature of ColorBrewer (and the associated `RColorBrewer` package). You'll notice that the warning disappears when you assign `color` to factors with equal to or more than three levels, e.g.

```
plot_ly(iris, x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width,
        color = cut(Sepal.Length, 3), colors = "Set1",
        mode = "markers")
```

This is because ColorBrewer's minimum number of data classes is three (which you can see from http://colorbrewer2.org/ where can't select fewer than three classes). For instance, in `?brewer.pal` (the function referenced by plotly), it specifically says

> All the sequential palettes are available in variations from 3
>   different values up to 9 different values.
>
> [...]
>
> For qualitative palettes, the lowest number of distinct values available always is 3

Since `build_plotly()` (the function `plotly()` calls internally) always calls `brewer.pal()` (see line 474 [here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/blob/master/R/plotly_build.R)), it's not possible to fix this without rewriting the `build_plotly()` function to not call `brewer.pal()` with fewer than 3 data classes.

In the meantime, to turn off the warning, assign the plot output to an object and wrap the `print(object)` statement in `suppressWarnings()` like this:

```
plotly_plot <- plot_ly(iris, x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width,
      color = Sepal.Length>6, colors = c("#132B43", "#56B1F7"),
      mode = "markers")

suppressWarnings(print(plotly_plot))
```

Comment: Makes sense. Filed a bug report about this: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/670

Comment: Any way I can get rid of this warning in the meantime? I've tried suppressing it but seem to be suppressing it in the wrong place as it still shows. I've also tried adding an unused third level to the factor. But that, too, doesn't seem to work.