# Plotly - How to change the Histogram colour?

Tags: r, colors, histogram, plotly

I am trying to plot a histogram with a specific colour since the purpose is to do create two histograms from two different data frames and I do not want to present both of them with the default blue colour. I am aware that a solution would imply the conversion of the ggplo2 object into plotly, but I would like to find out a way to solve this small problem in the plotly code.
The code for a basic plotly histogram is the following:

```
    plot_ly(x=~dataframe$variable, type="histogram") %>%
    layout(title="Histogram title", xaxis=list(title="X-axis title"))
```

The two solutions I have tried do not work:

1) First attempt:

```
    plot_ly(x=~dataframe$variable, type="histogram", color="green") %>%
    layout(title="Histogram title", xaxis=list(title="X-axis title"))
```

It returns the following warning message:

```
    In RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(N, "Set2") :
    minimal value for n is 3, returning requested palette with 3 different levels
```

2) Second attempt:

```
    plot_ly(x=~dataframe$variable, type="histogram", colour="green") %>%
    layout(title="Histogram title", xaxis=list(title="X-axis title"))
```

It returns the following warning message:

```
    'histogram' objects don't have these attributes: 'colour'
    Valid attributes include:
    'type', 'visible', 'showlegend', 'legendgroup', 'opacity', 'name', 'uid', 'ids', 'customdata', 'hoverinfo', 'hoverlabel', 'stream', 'x', 'y', 'text', 'orientation', 'histfunc', 'histnorm', 'cumulative', 'autobinx', 'nbinsx', 'xbins', 'autobiny', 'nbinsy', 'ybins', 'marker', 'error_y', 'error_x', '_deprecated', 'xaxis', 'yaxis', 'xcalendar', 'ycalendar', 'idssrc', 'customdatasrc', 'hoverinfosrc', 'xsrc', 'ysrc', 'textsrc', 'key', 'set', 'frame', 'transforms', '_isNestedKey', '_isSimpleKey', '_isGraticule'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, the same question have been described in the following hyperlink: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740837/custom-discrete-color-scale-in-plotly/38744227. In general the problem appears by "ColorBrewer", because the minimum number of data classes is three.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Daniel, but the histogram is still blue as default, even if I try to assign the plot output to an object and use the suppressWarnings() function. The hyperlink posted is related to the best way to hide the warning message, not to change the color of a histogram on plotly

Answer (score 3):

Does the plot below work? The `color` argument must be specified to the `marker` attribute.

```
library(plotly)
set.seed(1)
dataframe <- data.frame(variable = rnorm(1000))
plot_ly(x=~dataframe$variable, type="histogram", marker = list(color = 'green')) %>%
  layout(title="Histogram title", xaxis=list(title="X-axis title"))
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Ameya, I found many detailed information about other graphs on plotly, but unfortunately I missed this info on histograms.
It works fine now, thanks a million!